# Calculate total items per page (pagination logic)

Tags: ruby, logic

I need to check the total items of every page on pagination.
For example, I have 165 posts and a pagination with 4 links:
1,2,3,4

How can I discover the total items per page based on the number of pages generated?

Comment: You cannot unless you know the exact number of items on the last page because your example of 165 posts could be distributed across 4 pages in different ways, for example: [50, 50, 50, 15]  or [48, 48, 48, 21] or [45, 45, 45, 30]. Why do you need the total number of items per page? What do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: You marked this question as Ruby, so are you using a gem like kaminari? That certainly allows you to set the items per page and returns the total page count. https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're using for pagination, but the count for each page is generally set by a variable, then the remainder fills up the last page. It doesn't just output a random amount of the total on each page.

If using Kaminari, for example, there is a variable `config.default_per_page`.
Something like this should provide the answer.

`full_pages = total_posts / default_per_page`

`spill_over = total_posts - (default_per_page * full_pages)`